# How to align divs no matter which screen size

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a mini piano with divs. The colors, width, etc. all works well, and without any positioning or anything, it currently [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK0QC.png). So I gave it some absolute positioning, and gave it a bit of margin, and it now [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZE1a.png). However, because of the absolute positioning I gave it, when I change my screen size, the black keys start to misalign, for example it can [end up looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynUfR.png).

My Code:

```css
.container-fluid {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4rem 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

.white-note,
.black-note {
    display: inline-block;
}

.white-note {
    background-color: white;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 12rem;
    box-shadow: 6px 7px 17px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.black-note {
    background-color: black;
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 7rem;
}

.low-c-d-sharp {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 28.4vw;
}

.low-rest-sharp {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 43.7vw;
}

.low-f-sharp,
.low-g-sharp {
    margin-right: 1.45rem;
}

.high-c-d-sharp {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 63.5vw;
}

.high-c-sharp {
    margin-right: 1.4rem;
}

.low-c-sharp {
    margin-right: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<!-- Note: I'm also using Bootstrap -->

<div id="piano-keys-container" class="container-fluid">

  <div class="white-notes">
    <div class="low-c white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-d white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-e white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-f white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-g white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-a white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-b white-note"></div>
    <div class="high-c white-note"></div>
    <div class="high-d white-note"></div>
    <div class="high-e white-note"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="black-notes">
    <div class="low-c-d-sharp">
      <div class="low-c-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="low-d-sharp black-note"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="low-rest-sharp">
      <div class="low-f-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="low-g-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="low-a-sharp black-note"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="high-c-d-sharp">
      <div class="high-c-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="high-d-sharp black-note"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I think this may be a bad way to do it, but the only way I could think of.

I've also tried everything I know how to do and tried relative positioning, changing the units to px from rem, using media queries for the black keys, etc. but nothing seems to work, and the black keys just starts going everywhere the moment I change the screen size.

Is there a way to make the black keys stay where it's supposed to go (between the white keys) no matter what screen size it's viewed on? I've been stuck on this for quite a bit and would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Edit: Thanks so much for the help everyone!

Comment: You could stick with rems and try something like this: https://css-tricks.com/books/fundamental-css-tactics/scale-typography-screen-size/

Comment: @BillDoughty Ah I see, will try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for your reference. The keys align themselves irrespective of any screen size.

```css
.keys {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  max-width: 880px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.key {
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  transition: all 0.07s ease;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.key:not(.sharp) {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.key.sharp {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6%;
  height: 60%;
  background: #000;
  color: #eee;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.key[data-key="87"] {
  left: 7%;
}

.key[data-key="69"] {
  left: 17%;
}

.key[data-key="84"] {
  left: 37%;
}

.key[data-key="89"] {
  left: 47%;
}

.key[data-key="85"] {
  left: 57%;
}

.key[data-key="79"] {
  left: 77%;
}

.key[data-key="80"] {
  left: 87%;
}
```

```html
<div class="keys">
  <div data-key="65" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="87" class="key sharp">

  </div>
  <div data-key="83" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="69" class="key sharp">

  </div>
  <div data-key="68" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="70" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="84" class="key sharp">

  </div>
  <div data-key="71" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="89" class="key sharp">

  </div>
  <div data-key="72" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="85" class="key sharp">

  </div>
  <div data-key="74" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="75" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="79" class="key sharp">

  </div>
  <div data-key="76" class="key">

  </div>
  <div data-key="80" class="key sharp">

  </div>
  <div data-key="186" class="key">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! Just kind of curious about what type of selector this is. Once again, thanks!

Comment: @imp-pepe Hello, I'm glad that you found it useful. The data-* attribute gives the ability to embed custom attributes on all HTML elements. And hence, it can be useful when there are multiple divs with the same functionality but different position.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use **Viewport Units** like **vw** for **width** and **vh** for **height** instead of **px**, **rem** and **%** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive and it can be viewed on all screen sizes.

Try it, it will surely work and if it doesn't will let me know in the comments. I will try my best to help you.

```css
 .container-fluid {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4.685vw 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

.white-note,
.black-note {
    display: inline-block;
}

.white-note {
    background-color: white;
    width: 4.685vw;
    height: 14.05vw;
    box-shadow: 0.439vw 0.512vw 1.244vw 0.366vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.black-note {
    background-color: black;
    width: 2.928vw;
    height: 8.199vw;
}

.low-c-d-sharp {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 28.4vw;
}

.low-rest-sharp {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 43.7vw;
}

.low-f-sharp,
.low-g-sharp {
    margin-right: 1.698vw;
}

.high-c-d-sharp {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 63.5vw;
}

.high-c-sharp {
    margin-right: 1.639vw;
}

.low-c-sharp {
    margin-right: 1.639vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mini Piano</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="piano-keys-container" class="container-fluid">

  <div class="white-notes">
    <div class="low-c white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-d white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-e white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-f white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-g white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-a white-note"></div>
    <div class="low-b white-note"></div>
    <div class="high-c white-note"></div>
    <div class="high-d white-note"></div>
    <div class="high-e white-note"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="black-notes">
    <div class="low-c-d-sharp">
      <div class="low-c-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="low-d-sharp black-note"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="low-rest-sharp">
      <div class="low-f-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="low-g-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="low-a-sharp black-note"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="high-c-d-sharp">
      <div class="high-c-sharp black-note"></div>
      <div class="high-d-sharp black-note"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! One thing though, (maybe I'm doing this wrong), when I changed the 'left' property (the black keys have position absolute) from 'rem' to 'vw' units and changed the screen size, the black keys still doesn't align and starts moving around. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: @imp-pepe Can you please attach your new code in which you have converted **rem** into **vw** to help me assist you better.

Comment: Got it, will do so.
Alright, I updated the code in the question.

Comment: @imp-pepe I have added HTML and CSS code in my answer. Now your code is working,  and you just have to check are all the values according to you.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @imp-pepe So happy to listen that it worked. Can you please do me a favour by accepting my answer, it would mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is considered "aligning", but since the black is on top of the white, why not nest the black button inside the white altogether?

Positioning every key manually is impractical, in my opinion.

```css
/* CSS */

.piano-keys-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4rem 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.white-note,
.black-note {
  display: block;
}

.white-note {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 12rem;
  box-shadow: 6px 7px 17px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
}

.black-note {
  background-color: black;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 7rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<!-- Note: I'm also using Bootstrap -->

<div class="piano-keys-container">

  <div class="white-note">
    <div class="black-note"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-note">
    <div class="black-note"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note">
    <div class="black-note"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-note">
    <div class="black-note"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-note">
    <div class="black-note"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note">
    <div class="black-note"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-note">
    <div class="black-note"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>

</div>
```

Hopefully, from this example, you should be able to find out the changes I made, and the concept I took as an approach to this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'm trying to get the black keys in between the white keys instead of on top of it though. I think this will do for now, again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean like this? All you would need to do is add `float: left;` to the black keys css class and move it out of the white keys.

https://jsfiddle.net/ochen1/hs107qrb/21/

Comment: The positioning is where I want it to be, thanks! However, the black keys need to kind of be on top of the white keys instead of beside the white keys. So its kind of like taken out of the flow and put on top of the white keys (sorry if this is not too clear).

Comment: why not do a search like html css piano layout before you post?  There's a great solution on codepen

Comment: Sorry about that, my language interpretation skills have degraded.
I updated the fiddle again. Is this the type of positioning you want?
https://jsfiddle.net/ochen1/hs107qrb/39/

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure! Hope you learned something new and find out why these changes work!